# Intersecting 3D line Segments

Tags: 3d, geometry, line-segment

How do I determine whether or not two 3D line segments intersect given XYZ coordinates for the start and end points of each line?  If they do intersect, at what XYZ?

I've only been able to find answers for 2D: [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

Comment: this should be on Math math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you talking about line segments or infinite lines?

Comment: @MBo Sorry, line segments.

Answer (score 7):

Let's starting points are P0, Q0, and ending points are P1, Q1.

```
Direction vectors
DP = P1 - P0
DQ = Q1 - Q0
start difference vector
PQ = Q0 - P0
```

Segment in parametric form:

```
P = P0 + t * DP
Q = Q0 + u * DQ
```

Find values

```
a = Dot(DP, DP)
b = Dot(DP, DQ)
c = Dot(DQ, DQ)
d = Dot(DP, PQ)
e = Dot(DQ, PQ)
```

Find discriminant

```
DD = a * c- b * b
```

If DD = 0, then segments are parallel, and consider special case of (partial) coincidence, else

Find parameters for the closest points on lines

```
tt = (b * e - c * d) / DD
uu = (a * e - b * d) / DD
```

If any parameter is out of range 0..1, then segments don't intersect, else

Find distance between points

```
 P(tt) = P0 + tt * DP
 Q(uu) = Q0 + uu * DQ
 Dist = Length(Q(uu) - P(tt))
```

If Dist is zero (or less than some small Epsilon value like 1.0E-12 due to numerical errors), then segments are intersect in this point P(tt)

Comment: I tried to implement it in c++ but i cant make it work

Comment: https://gist.github.com/soulslicer/26c4d6d36407e37c21cdf033c532a9ca

Comment: @raaj Wrong in the beginning: `DP(P[3]-P[0], P[4]-P[1], P[5]-P[2]);` and similar for DQ

Comment: In my code the vector P consits of the point and the vector. so P(0 to 2) is the point and P(3 to 5) is the normalized vector

Comment: Similar approach has been used many times. Look code [here](https://www.geometrictools.com/GTE/Samples/Distance/DistanceSegments3/DistanceSegments3Console.cpp), function `DistanceSegments3Console`. Or [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a07-_distance.html). Substitute some simple points (0 0 0-1 0 0, 0 1 0-0 0 1) and check intermediate values

Comment: I suspect the sign of the discrimnant may be flipped in this code

Comment: @Makogan What do you mean?

Comment: @MBo I tried this algorithm on a bunch of tests and it was consistently giving values for tt and uu that were in the opposite direciton of what I expected. once I did -dd instead of dd, things worked.